# Cypress test always fails in GitHub Actions & headless, but not locally in normal mode?

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test that checks for the presence of a `data-cy` within another `data-cy`.

This test passes when I run Cypress locally in Chrome. It fails when I run it in headless mode locally. It fails regardless of what mode it is run under, when ran in GitHub Actions.

When it fails locally in headless mode, I can see the element rendered that it is apparently failing to find on the DOM, in the screenshots & video.

I'm baffled. I've tried changing Node versions on GitHub Actions, I've tried a separate Cypress test step rather than using the Vue CLI. I've even tried running it within a Windows container and forcing Chrome instead of Electron. I've even tried adding sleeps/timeouts.

Here is the test:

```
  it("When I choose 4-4-2, I see the expected combination of players", () => {
    cy.get("[data-cy=formation-selector-1]").select("4-4-2");
    cy.get("[data-cy=formation-1]").within(() => {
      cy.get("[data-cy=goalkeeper]")
        .its("length")
        .should("eq", 1);
    });
  });
```

The error message always says:
`CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '[data-cy=goalkeeper]', but never found it.`

Does anyone have any idea, what the culprit possibly could be? Or something I can do to get to the bottom of it? Thanks.

Comment: What's interesting is that you're using within() here when you might not need it. The use of data-cy attribute suggests a unique id to the page. My guess is that whatever goalkeeper is, it isn't inside of  whatever 'data-cy=formation-1' is. Recommend double checking the hierarchy and consider removing that second cy.get().within() and go straight after the goalkeeper. btw: I wasn't the downvote.

Comment: @GrayDwarf data-cy=formation-1 is a particular div on the page with another div inside of it with data-cy=goalkeeper on it. Within is required because there are other data-cy=goalkeeper's on the page under data-cy=formation-2 for example. The issue can be solved if I append a -1 to each goalkeeper element, but it is weird why the within() selector works fine running Cypress locally in non-headless mode, but does not work in GitHub Actions/headless locally. So it certainly isn't a hierarchical error.

Comment: Technically, that should work even with the duped data-cy attributes. It could be a cypress bug or could be by design just as easily. I'd mention the dupe data-cy elements in your github issue so it helps with the investigation.